# Music sounds all choppy

Tags: technical-issues, civilization-5

Whenever I start up Civilisation V the music and sound effects all sound choppy and horrible. I have tried restarting the game and my computer but to no avail. I am on a Ubuntu 14.04 computer running the Linux version, although it only started doing this recently.

What is causing this problem and how can I fix it?

Comment: Did you try to update your audio drivers?

Comment: No, and I wouldn't know how to either.

Comment: Old audio drivers are responsible for 50% of all soundbugs. I'd highly recommend you're looking up how to do it on your system or at least specify the soundcard/motherboard so we can help you.